# Type TypeB should re use Interface InterfaceA

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a following TypeScript code.

```
interface InterfaceA {
  id: string;
  key: string;
  value: string | number;
}

type TypeB = null;

const sample: TypeB = { id: '1' };
```

I need few simple and maintainable solutions where `TypeB` should reuse `InterfaceA` to correctly implement `const example: B = ...`.

I tried below which works fine but I am not sure if this is the best and maintainable approach.

```
interface InterfaceA {
  id: string;
  key: string;
  value: string | number;
}

type TypeB = InterfaceA & null;

const sample: TypeB = { id: '1' } as TypeB;
```

***How can I do this in more than one approach?***

Comment: What is type `A` and `B`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `type TypeB = null` makes no sense. Why would you type alias null? Intersecting an interface and null also makes no sense as it just yields null.

Comment: Maybe you want to use ```interface TypeB extends TypeA{}```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the `Partial` utility type to make the properties of `InterfaceA` optional. This might be better than just using an intersection of `null`.

```
interface InterfaceA {
    id: string;
    key: string;
    value: string | number;
}

type TypeB = Partial<InterfaceA>;

const sample: TypeB = { id: '1' };
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's start by understanding how null works in Typescript.

Typescript has two very different ways of handling null and undefined. If `--strictNullChecks` is true, then null and undefined are both essentially literal types, types whose only member is null or undefined respectively. If `--strictNullChecks` is false then null and undefined are members of every type.

Next let's explain intersection types `type T = A & B` means that for a value to be of type T it must be of both type A and type B. So {a:string} & {b:string} is {a:string, b:string}. Intersections of non interface types are basically nonsense. What is `string & number`? No value is both a string and a number, so no value satisfies the type.

Ok, now let's look at your code `type TypeB = null` aliases the null type. Then `const sample: TypeB = {id: '1'}` is invalid Typescript. It won't compile, because an object is not null.

In your second example `type TypeB = InterfaceA & null` depends on the compiler settings. With strict null checks on TypeB is InterfaceA, with them off it is null. I leave it as an exercise to figure out why that is. In either case it doesn't do anything. The only reason your code compiles is that you use `as TypeB`. Typescript type assertions are unsafe. You can cast any type to any type. Which is why `as` should only be used in very narrow cases (mostly dealing with genuinely unknown data, like that coming from a serialization function).

So in the end, it's not at all clear what you want to do, but your code as written makes no sense, and you should probably spend some time reading the Typescript docs.